# angular2/javascript - NgFor looping through array inside of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, angular2-template

I have my own object with data which I loop through using ngFor. However there is an array part in the object, which I want to loop through as well in a `<li></li>`

Currently it looks like this. However I don't want the complete string in one `<li></li>` I just want one piece of the array there.
[image: Complete string is displayed]

Relevant Code:

**tier.model**

```
export class Tier {
  constructor (
    public id: number,
    public title: string,
    public rewards: any[],
    public price: number
  )
  {}
}
```

**component:**

```
export class PackagesComponent {  //will be renamed to TierComponent
  public tierToEdit: Tier;
  editMode = false;
  tiers: Tier[] = [
    new Tier(
      10,
      'First Tier',
      ['Server access - Simple', 'Win something small', 'and so on'],
      5.00),
    new Tier(
      11,
      'Second Tier',
      ['Server access - Standard', 'Win something medium', 'and so on and on'],
      10.00),
    new Tier(
      12,
      'Third Tier',
      ['Server access - Advanced', 'Win something big', 'and so on and on and on'],
      10.00)
  ]
```

**template:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div  class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let tier of tiers; let i=index;">
    <ul class="pricing-table">
      <li class="plan-name">
        {{ tier.title }}
      </li>
      <li *ngFor="let reward of tiers">
        {{ reward.rewards }}
      </li>
      <p class="plan-price">{{ tier.price }}</p>
      <li class="plan-action">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onEdit(tier)">Edit</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success" (click)="this.clickSave()">SaveYes</a>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" >Get</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

In the end it should look like this:

[image: should look like this]

Something else I tried was this:

```
<div  class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let tier of tiers; let i=index;">
    <!-- Show Mode -->
    <ul *ngIf="!editMode || tierToEdit != tier" class="pricing-table">
      <li class="plan-name">
        {{ tier.title }}
      </li>
      <li *ngFor="let reward of tiers; let i=index">
        {{ reward.rewards[i] }}
      </li>
```

Which than gave me the first element of the first array, the second element of the second array and the third element of the third array:[image]

Hope this is not to confusing, still very new to angular/javascript, sorry for possibly asking stupid question or using wrong terms :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Please create a plnkr or fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate on nested array in 2nd `*ngFor` as well, Like :

```
 <div class="row">
   <div  class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let tier of tiers; let i=index;">
    <ul class="pricing-table">
      <li class="plan-name">
        {{ tier.title }}
      </li>
      <li *ngFor="let reward of tier.rewards">
        {{reward}}
      </li>
      <p class="plan-price">{{ tier.price }}</p>
      <li class="plan-action">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onEdit(tier)">Edit</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success" (click)="this.clickSave()">SaveYes</a>
        <a class="btn btn-warning" >Get</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: wow, I feel incredibly stupid. Thanks a lot, that worked.
Didn't know I could user tier.rewards, thought it would need to be tierS.rewards, since that's the way I define it in my component.ts
Thank you very much!

Comment: so basically the tier now refers to the tier above? http://puu.sh/wekZj/c85bc73f5a.png just asking so I understand for the future

Comment: @junior_dn : yes `tier` refer to 1st `*ngFor`, no matter how many ngFor you have inside, since *ngFor create `block scope`, like `var in javascript`... and glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   <li *ngFor="let reward of tier.rewards">
        {{ reward }}
   </li>
```